# How to add a logo to top main menu in Arcade wordpress theme?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'd like to add a logo (aligned far left) in the top navigation main-menu on my homepage: http://cricketyorkshire.com. *I've included my site then National Geographic website below as an example of logo placement*

[image]

[image: sample menu from nat Geo website]

I'd like the logo to fit within the grey nav bar with the menu items - CLUB CRICKET etc moved further over to the right.

The wordpress theme is Arcade. This may or may not be something I can do myself as I'm not knowledgable with code but keen to give it a go. The site is backed up with host WPEngine so I can restore a previous version quickly.

Any advice would be really appreciated, both code and for this novice, if I drop into custom CSS or add to a source file?

Comment: I would create a child theme, and then recreate the header.php to your needings.

Comment: how to create a child theme : http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-create-a-wordpress-child-theme-video/

Comment: @Stender will explore child themes, that will also solve minor theme changes that occur with WP updates. Any ideas on coding itself within header.php for adding a logo to the main-menu?